# Can I use ffmpeg's default Arial font commercially-free?

Tags: ffmpeg, fonts, subtitle

I'm trying to find out if I can use ffmpeg's default Arial font commercially-free when burning subtitles to videos.

There are a lot of Arial fonts out there and I don't know which ones are free to use. I'm just trying to use the one that comes default with ffmpeg.

I know that Arial MS can be used on a Windows machine but I will use ffmpeg in an Ubuntu machine.

Thank you for your concern.

Comment: What about using [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/) or some other service to find a font with the appropriate license?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a legal question and not a problem that can be solved via software.

Comment: @HernánAlarcón For some reason, when I burn subtitles with FFmpeg, only the default Arial font works with Arabic. That's why I'm trying to get that font.

Answer (score 1):

FFmpeg does not come with any fonts. FFmpeg uses `libass` to burn subtitles, which in turn uses fontconfig to scan fonts available on system and use them.